# Touch events available in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, multi-touch

A friend and I were discussing Mozilla's latest [touch support](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/firefox4-beta3/) and got on the question of what Safari provides for this. Searches seem to turn up nothing.

Do you know of anything that provides touch events to Safari on desktop, either via multitouch trackpad or direct screen interaction (I guess a Windows multitouch environment would be the only relevant case here.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is currently no support for touch events in the desktop version of Safari.

According to [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/TouchEventClassReference/TouchEvent/TouchEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009358) it is only supported on iOS 2.0 or later.