# With elastic bounce Chrome/Safari knows when my fingers leave the trackpad. Can JS know?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, desktop

When you overscroll a page in Chrome or Safari you can hold the page "overscrolled" and it will bounce back only after you lift your fingers from the trackpad. I would like to recreate this event, can JS detect when you lift your fingers from laptop's trackpad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It looks like trackpad touch events cannot be detected in the browser.

- [JQuery - Can I query the MacBook Pro Trackpad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677783/jquery-can-i-query-the-macbook-pro-trackpad)
- [Touch events available in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472889/touch-events-available-in-safari)

---

**Aside**

This is a reference for all browser events:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events